# Hide username and date in Drupal page

Tags: drupal-6

I need to make a completely blank page in Drupal. If I don't give body of the page then it is showing the username and date as must. Is there any way to hide this information?

Or can I get the method which generates the contents of a page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to go to the admin panel. In Site building->Themes->Configure->Global Settings there's a box titled "display post information". Tick or untic the content types where you want to show/hide the info.

If you want to do it the hard way, then yes, there is a way of doing it in PHP. In your theme code, you can create a template for either your content type or even an individual page (node-24.tpl.php, where 24 is your node's NID). There, you can write anything you consider necessary, like:

```
<?php
    echo "<h2>$title</h2>";
    echo $content;
```

This will display only the page title and the page body, with no additional sweetness whatsoever :).